# HTML Email signature NOT rendering correct only on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, email, signature

this is actually the first time I post a question, but I usually "always" find the answers here. You guys are great!...

Here's my issue (belive me I have tried to find an answer). 
I have created an email signature using standard HTML/inline CSS using tables. It looks great almost everywhere and with many different email clients... well, except for the iPhone/iPad

I am attaching an exact copy of my code as well as an image of it should look on the iphone (it looks fine almost everywhere else I have test it like hotmail, live, gmail, office 365, roundcube etc). It looks to me that the iphone renders the font/text to a set size and does NOT respect what I have used as font-size. I have tried tweaking my html code from divs to table, from moving styles from td to spans etc, and nothing.

*NOTE: it will not let me upload an image, so I have uploaded to the web here: http://www.ileansolutions.com/ditthavong/uploads/images/test_email_signature.jpg

```
<table width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" cols="2">

<tr>
<td width="400" colspan="2"><img src="http://ileansolutions.com/ditthavong/uploads/images/ditthavong_em_sig.jpg" width="400" height="34" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td width="400" colspan="2" style="background-color:#999999; color:#ffffff; width:auto; height:10px;"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="400" colspan="2" style="padding: 10px 0 5px 0;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#717070; font-size:17px;">Kevin Smith</span></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="180"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:11px;">Office 703.500.9900</span></td>
<td width="220" style="text-align:right;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:11px;">44 Canal Center Plaza, Suite 322</span></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="190"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:11px;">Direct 703.500.9900</span></td>
<td width="210" style=" text-align:right;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:11px;">Alexandria, Virginia 22314 USA</span></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="400" colspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffff; color:#ffffff; width:auto; height:10px;"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td width="400" colspan="2" style="background-color:#999999; padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;"><span style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:14px;">email@domain.com</span></td>
</tr>

</table>

<br/>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<span style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;">******** PRIVILEGED AND CONFIDENTIAL COMMUNICATION *********</span>
<br/>
<span style="font-size:11px;">THIS MESSAGE IS BEING SENT FROM THE LAW OFFICES OF SO AND SO ETC. THIS MESSAGE IS BEING SENT FROM THE LAW OFFICES OF SO AND SO ETC. THIS MESSAGE IS BEING SENT FROM THE LAW OFFICES OF SO AND SO ETC. THIS MESSAGE IS BEING SENT FROM THE LAW OFFICES OF SO AND SO ETC. THIS MESSAGE IS BEING SENT FROM THE LAW OFFICES OF SO AND SO ETC.        </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did the shake the iPhone solution work for you?

Answer (score 7):

iOS changes text sizes and colors automatically. But luckily, you can undo this! After pasting your signature in Settings, *shake* your iPhone to bring up the Undo dialog. Choose "Undo Change Attributes." Boom. Back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The "shake your iPhone" to "Undo Change attributes" works well, including for getting the signature to display correctly in Outlook.  If you don't "undo change attributes" then Outlook users will see the whole email - email content and signature - in a Times New Roman font.

This is because Outlook defaults to showing any HTML text that is not specified to a certain font, as Times New Roman.  When you initially paste your signature into the iOS settings Apple removes whatever specific font you coded.  But when you choose "undo change attributes" it puts that HTML code back in.

However one thing to be aware of for Outlook - the **content** of your email will still appear as Times New Roman, even when you signature appears correctly in a sans font (assuming you chose a sans font). This is because iOS doesn't specify the font in HTML emails, which causes Outlook to fall back to Times New Roman.

This fall back font for Outlook can be changed on each users computer (http://www.msoutlook.info/question/521), but there doesn't seem to be a way to force the body font to be specified for all viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these will make a difference, but it's better than no answer at all:

Try using `<font>` tags instead of `<span>`.

Try using `font-size:17px !important;`